# OpenVPN struggling

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn

I've got some problems with my OpenVPN setup.

**The Setup:**
-> Ubuntu Server 12.04
-> Two active NIC's: eth0 (default): 192.168.1.0/24
eth1: x.x.x.x (external ip)

I've managed to get the routing to work so i can connect to the outside world with the eth1 NIC.

```
holmen@filserver:~$ ping -I eth1 -c 3 www.linuxquestions.org
PING www.linuxquestions.org (75.126.162.205) from 192.168.1.2 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.linuxquestions.org (75.126.162.205): icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=133 ms
64 bytes from www.linuxquestions.org (75.126.162.205): icmp_req=2 ttl=50 time=133 ms
64 bytes from www.linuxquestions.org (75.126.162.205): icmp_req=3 ttl=50 time=133 ms

--- www.linuxquestions.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 133.281/133.336/133.379/0.423 ms
One curious thing is that the "from ip #". It says "from 192.168.1.2 eth1" but that ip is the servers ip on the eth0 iface.
```

**Netstat:**

```
holmen@filserver:~$ netstat -anr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
x.x.x.x     0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

**But here comes the real problem:**
When setting up openvpn with the option "local x.x.x.x (eth1 ext ip)" it still tunnels the eth0 interface. And i cant understand why.

**OpenVPN settings:**

```
client

dev tap

proto udp

local x.x.x.x

remote openvpn.anonine.net 1194
remote openvpn.anonine.net 1195
remote openvpn-2.anonine.net 1196
remote openvpn-2.anonine.net 1197
remote openvpn-3.anonine.net 1198
remote openvpn-3.anonine.net 1199
remote openvpn-4.anonine.net 1200
remote openvpn-4.anonine.net 1201

remote-random

resolv-retry infinite

auth-user-pass

persist-key
persist-tun

ca anonine.ca.crt

ns-cert-type server

comp-lzo

reneg-sec 0

verb 3
```

**Netstat (tunnel active):**

```
holmen@filserver:~$ netstat -anr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         46.246.20.129   128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tap0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
5.150.128.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
46.246.20.128   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U         0 0          0 tap0
80.67.8.222     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
128.0.0.0       46.246.20.129   128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tap0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want OpenVPN client’s to follow a certain route, correct? If so, try adding it to the server config. I have included the server config of one of my test labs below, I added local `<ext eth1 ip>` to the server config:

```
local xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
port 443
proto tcp
dev tap1
ca cacert.pem
cert servercert.pem
key servercert-unencr.key
dh dh1024.pem
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 20 120
tun-mtu 1500
server-bridge 192.168.200.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.200.10 192.168.200.15
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp-generic.txt
comp-lzo
duplicate-cn
daemon
verb 3
#redirect-gateway def1
push "route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0"
log-append /etc/openvpn/logs/ovpn-generic.log
up /etc/openvpn/ifconfig-tap1.sh
cd /etc/openvpn
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN lab.test"
push "dhcp-option NBT 2"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.100.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 4.2.2.2"
script-security 3 system
```

I will update if you have questions.

**UPDATE:** You have an entry in your routing table that's pointing all your traffic through your eth0 interface:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

That should either be changed to eth1 Iface and `eth1`’s IP for the gateway or removed entirely since you already have a route for your local network, and it’s conflicting with your other default route:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         46.246.20.129   128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tap0
```

My educated guess is the destination is the same, but the 2nd entry is taking precedence.

Comment: I'm not the one hosting the server since it's a anonymizer service.

Comment: So the Ubuntu machine you mentioned above is not the OpenVPN server, but the OpenVPN client?

Comment: Thats correct. I'm trying to connect to the anonymizer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `netstat` shows that the *VPN server provider* is redirecting your client gateway (which is standard practice for *VPN anonymizer services*).  This means it will tunnel **all** traffic, regardless of what interface is the source.  What you need is `route-nopull` in your client config, which will stop the server changing your routing table, allowing you to manually create the routes you require.